# Convert Byte Array to Charsequence in Android

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, charsequence

I have used the below code to convert Charsequence to Byte Array. Then I save the Byte Array as Blob to my Sqlite Database.

For this , I have used the below code,

```
 public static byte[] toByteArray(CharSequence charSequence) {
        if (charSequence == null) {
          return null;
        }
        byte[] barr = new byte[charSequence.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < barr.length; i++) {
          barr[i] = (byte) charSequence.charAt(i);
        }

        return barr;
      }
```

Now I would like to convert my byte array retrieved from sqlite to Charsequence. But I couldn't get any help on it.

**How to convert Byte Array to Charsequence?**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this ASCII only? Because if not, that conversion will lose data.

Comment: `CharSequence` is an interface, so you need an actual implementation to put your byte array into...

Comment: @Thilo  No my firned. It is TSCII format. I am working for a Indic language app. Loss of data might affect my html sequence I believe.

Comment: If you got a CharSequence in Android, it has already been transformed to Unicode (or is already broken). Why not use UTF-8 for everything in your system, and then (maybe, if really required) convert it to TSCII for import/export to whatever else you are running there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To convert a `CharSequence` into a byte array

```
CharSequence seq;
Charset charset;
...
byte[] bytes = seq.toString().getBytes(charset);
```

To convert back again

```
CharSequence seq2 = new String(bytes, charset);
```

Just remember that `CharSequence` is an interface that is implemented by `String`, `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, etc so all `String` instances are `CharSequence` instances but not all `CharSequence` instances are `String` but the contract for `CharSequence` is that its `toString()` method should return the equivalent `String`

Internally all strings in Java are represented as Unicode, so as long as the consumer and producer are both Java the safest charset to use is one of `UTF-8` or `UTF-16` depending on the likely encoding size of your data. Where Latin scripts predominate,

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

will 99.9% of the time give the most space efficient encoding, for non-latin character sets (e.g. Chinese) you may find `UTF-16` more space efficient depending on the data set you are encoding. You would need to have measurements showing that it is a more space efficient encoding and as `UTF-8` is more widely expected I recommend `UTF-8` as the default encoding in any case.

Comment: +1 for showing the proper way to encode a CharSequence in the first place.

Comment: If you are really caught in a TSCII encoding nightmare, you may find this: http://unicode.org/notes/tn15/Tscii2Unicode2.pdf helpful

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are using ASCII data (if not, your code is quite lossy).

To get a CharSequence from ASCII bytes, you can do

```
CharSequence x = new String(theBytes, "US-ASCII");
```

For other encodings, just specify the name of the character set.

Comment: What If I want to use TSCII type? Is that possible?

Comment: +1 I would use `ISO-8852-1` which is 8-bit characters whereas `US-ASCII` is technically 7-bit. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: I am not sure if Java supports TSCII. Cannot you use UTF-8? Where do you get the data from (the original CharSequence that you wrote into the DB)?

Comment: @AndroSelva I would try TSCII, but it might not be supported on all platforms.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: But that won't match his "encoder" (which is just taking the first byte of every Unicode codepoint). Nothing will survive that except for 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @AndroSelva [Here you go](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). There is a contructor `String(byte[], CharSet charset)` to get full control over the charset.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am doing this for Android. And android doesn't support inidc language. So I need to make use of TSCII type data.

Comment: @AndroSelva You also have to make sure that your encoder (the code you posted above) converts the `CharSequence` to a `byte[]` using the encoding that you want to use. Now you're only casting `char`s to `byte`s.

Comment: Are you sure Android supports `TSCII`? All Java based systems should support UTF-8 so I would try this first.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Re: "Nothing will survive that except for 7-bit ASCII". Actually, it seems that it will work for ISO/IEC 8859-1 which makes up the second block of Unicode code points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1_Controls_and_Latin-1_Supplement

Comment: @Thilo It may happen to work on some systems, or it may work as documented on some Android systems. I would go with the one which is documented to always work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
CharSequence c = new String(byte[]);
```

Comment: Note that this will use the default character encoding of your system to interpret the bytes as characters. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Fair point - you will need to let know the charset in the constructor if you are not using the default.  Uboat for you sir!  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html